# TypeError: hook() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, deep-learning, hook, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch and I'm trying to use `hook()` and `register_forward_pre_hook` in my project

What I've tried is

```py
def get_features_hook(module,input):
    print(input)

handle_feat = alexnet.features[0].register_forward_pre_hook(get_features_hook)


a = alexnet(input_data)
```

And I got belows error at `a = alexnet(input_data)`

> TypeError: get_features_hook() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I've lost few hours on this problem and I just can't able to figure it out.

Anyone likes to help me?

---

With Shai's help, I tried his codes, and I got this

```
Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
get_features_hook called with 2 args:
    arg of type Conv2d
    arg of type tuple

File "<input>", line 2, in get_features_hook
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

Comment: what version of pytorch are you using?

Comment: @Shai is 1.2.0.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. pytorch 1.2.0. please provide a complete and minimal code that reproduce the error you got.

Answer (score 1):

If `get_features_hook` is defined inside your `torch.nn.Module`, it should be annotated as `@staticmethod`, otherwise `self` is implicitly passed to it

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I've tried re-running the notebook and that solved it